# Projection operator onto image of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra

This is probably not very difficult but somehow I am not grasping it. Let $Q$ be a positive semidefinite operator on a finite dimensional vector space and let $\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}$ be a projection operator onto the image of $Q$. A theorem I wanted to prove involves an observation that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{Q} = \sqrt{Q}\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)} = \Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}\sqrt{Q}\,.
\end{align}
Intuitively it might make sense because the projector brings any element in the domain to $\text{im}(Q)$ so $\sqrt{Q}$ would not bring things out of this, but it is not clear to me at all why the above relationship should hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I think I figured out the answer (funny because I didn't figure out this for a long time few days ago but now it just clicks, hopefully no mistake here). The idea is to write the direct sum decomposition $V=\ker{Q}\oplus\text{im }{Q}$ so that any $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as $v=w+u$ where $w\in \ker Q$ and $u\in \text{im }Q$. Therefore, $\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}v = u$ and hence $\sqrt{Q}\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}v=\sqrt{Q}u = \sqrt{Q}\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}u$. Furthermore, we also know that $\text{im }(Q)=\text{im}(\sqrt{Q})$ and hence $\sqrt{Q}u\in\text{im}(\sqrt{Q}) = \text{im}(Q)$ which implies that $\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}\sqrt{Q}u = \sqrt{Q}u$.

A potential confusion here I had stems from the fact that  $\sqrt{Q}\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}v=\sqrt{Q}u$ makes it look like as if $\sqrt{Q}\Pi_{\text{im}(Q)}\neq \sqrt{Q}$ since they act on vectors belonging to different vector spaces ($u\in \text{im}(Q)\subseteq V$).